# Program outputing "Heads" Regardless of Randomly Generated Answer

Tags: c++, if-statement, random, output

I'm new to C++ and was wondering why no matter what the random number that is generated is, the output is always heads. I assume that the function is defaulting to the first if statement is reads, but I don't know how to get it to check both options before outputting the text. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int coinToss(int);
int main()
{
 int input;
 int counter;
 int toss;
 int check;
 cout<<"Enter the number of times the coin will be tossed:";
 cin>>input;
 coinToss(input);
 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}

int coinToss(int input)
{
 int toss;
 int counter = 1;
 while(counter<=input)
 {
  toss = rand() % 2 + 1;
  int check = toss;
  cout<<check<<endl;
  if (toss = 1)
  {
  cout<<"Heads"<<endl;
  }
  else if (toss = 2)
  {
  cout<<"Tails"<<endl;
  }
  counter += 1;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need ==, not =

= is assignment
== is comparison.

What happens is that

```
toss = 1
```

assigns the value 1 to toss. This is then assessed as a boolean, which resolves to true. So you always get heads.

Answer (score 4):

This is *assigment* not an equality check:

```
if (toss = 1)
```

it results in `toss` being set to `1` and the result of the assignment is `1`, meaning the `if` branch is always entered. Use `==`:

```
if (toss == 1)
```

Same error for the `if else` condition.

Note the program has undefined behaviour as `coinToss()` does not return an `int` but has return type `int`:

```
int coinToss(int input)
{
    // no return!
}
```

Either make the return type `void` or return an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The following is an assignment, not comparison:

```
if (toss = 1)
```

Change it to

```
if (toss == 1)
```

The same goes for `toss = 2`.

It is a good idea to enable compiler warnings (`-Wall` in gcc). Most good compilers would have warned you about the erroneous assignments.

Comment: Also, turn on warnings in your compiler - they will 100% certain catch this one.